# Correct conversion of time strings containing PM

Tags: time-date

I have reached the outer edges of frustration on this one. I want to take a time stamp that is in the format: "Jan 20, 2023 7:09 PM" and get an output like: (0 9 19 20 1 2023 nil -1 nil) instead of (0 9 7 20 1 2023 nil -1 nil).

My current buffer of test code is:

```
(progn 
(setq date_string "Jan 20, 2023")                          (print date_string)
(setq am_pm_string "7:09 PM")                              (print am_pm_string)
(setq slacktime (format "%s %s" date_string am_pm_string)) (print slacktime)
(setq unixtime (parse-time-string slacktime))              (print unixtime)
(setq unixstart (round (time-to-seconds (date-to-time slacktime))))
(print unixstart)

(setq hhmm (format-time-string "%H%M" (encode-time unixtime))) (print hhmm)
)
```

Comment: And yeah, I could parse out the PM and add 12 to it, but it just seems like there should be a way to handle 12 hour clock time strings natively.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Here is something that can help convert am/pm to 24 hour using the `org.el` and `appt.el` libraries:  `(org-minutes-to-clocksum-string (appt-convert-time "7:09 PM"))` will return `19:09`.  The latter function first converts the am/pm time to minutes past midnight.  And, of course, we can use `require` to load the applicable libraries ...  I had trouble locating these with a plethora of Google searches .. at some point, a great question/answer might be `How to convert am/pm time to "hh:mm"?`

Comment: If you write your time as `7:09PM` with no space, then ` (decode-time (org-read-date nil t "Jan 20, 2023 7:09pm"))` works - I think.

Comment: Thanks much. Once I figured out there was a debian org-mode package and added: (unless (fboundp 'package-activate-all) (package-initialize))
(load-library "org")
(load-library "appt")  I got your suggestion to work.